# Using Linq to GroupBy and Case When via datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by, case-when

`enter code here`I have a Datatable like this:

```
LN             Test_Code        Name       Test_Item_Code        Test_Data  
0107001             A010         Yo             V0001               1  
0107001             A010         Yo             V0002               2  
0107001             C040         Yo             V0002               1  
0107001             C040         Yo             V0002               2   
0107002             C040         JC             V0001               3  
0107002             C040         JC             V0002               4  
0107003             C040         kk             V0001               5  
0107003             C040         kk             V0002               6
```

I need to get my datatable like this:

```
LN             Test_Code     Name     DueDate(V0001)        DueDate2(V00002)
0107001          A010         Yo           1                    2
0107001          C040         Yo           1                    2  
0107002          C040         JC           3                    4
0107003          C040         kk           5                    6
```

This is my SQLcommand if I can you case when.

```
select LN, Test_Code, Name, 
case when Test_Item_Code = 'V0001' then Test_Data else '' end as DueDate(V0001),
case when Test_Item_Code = 'V0002' then Test_Data else '' end as DueDate2(V0002)
From dt Group by LN, Test_Code, Name
```

This is my source code now. It's still error because I don't know how to get field Test_Item_Code and Test_Data to case when.

```
DataTable dt = services.getData();
var data = dt.AsEnumerable()
          .GroupBy(r1 => new
         {LN = r1["LN"],
          Test_Code = r1["Test_Code"],
          Name = r1["Name"],
          Test_Item_Code = r1["Test_Item_Code"],
          Test_Data = r1["Test_Data"] 
         }).Select(g => new
         {LN = g.Key.LN,
          Test_Code = g.Key.Test_Code,
          Name = g.Key.Name,
          DueDate = g.Key.Test_Item_Code == "V0001" ? g.Key.Test_Data : "",
          DueDate2 = g.Key.Test_Item_Code == "V0002" ? g.Key.Test_Data : ""
         });
```

I got data like this from above code:

```
LN             Test_Code     Name     DueDate(V0001)        DueDate2(V00002)
0107001          A010         Yo           1                    
0107001          A010         Yo                                2
0107001          C040         Yo           1                    
0107001          C040         Yo                                2
0107002          C040         JC           3                    
0107002          C040         JC                                4
0107003          C040         kk           5                    
0107003          C040         kk                                6
```

Anyone help/advice if possible would be really appreciated. I'm very new to linq.

## Solution

```
var data = dt.Select().GroupBy(r1 => r1["LN"])
         .SelectMany(r => r.GroupBy(g => g["Test_Code"]).Select(rr =>
            new
            {
                LN = r.Key,
                Test_Code = rr.Key,
                Name = rr.First()["Name"],
                DueDate = rr.OrderBy(r1 => r1["Test_Item_Code"] == "V0001").First()["Test_Data"],
                DueDate2 = rr.OrderBy(r1 => r1["Test_Item_Code"] == "V0002").First()["Test_Data"],
            }
          ));
```

Comment: I don't see any need for a group by in that SQL. Is that the full statement? What are you trying to achieve by using group  by there?

Comment: Hi Ben, Sorry for put wrong code. I have been to edit my code already. Please try to see again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Group by NL and then by Test_Code, this is an example:

```
var data = dt.Select().GroupBy(r1 => r1["LN"])
         .SelectMany(r => r.GroupBy(g => g["Test_Code"]).Select(rr =>
            new
            {
                LN = r.Key,
                Test_Code = rr.Key,
                Name = rr.First()["Name"],
                DueDate = rr.FirstOrDefault(r1 => r1["Test_Item_Code"] == "V0001")["Test_Data"],
                DueDate2 = rr.FirstOrDefault(r1 => r1["Test_Item_Code"] == "V0002")["Test_Data"],
            }
          ));
```

Comment: Thank you Elvis, Yes. Actually I have much more rows for each LN. Please see my datatable again. And sorry for first information.

Comment: I tried. I got error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at data.
DO you have other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Got it now!! Thank you so much Elvis, I changed your code a bit at last line to

DueDate = rr.OrderBy(r1 => r1["Test_Item_Code"] == "V0001").First()["Test_Data"],
                DueDate2 = rr.OrderBy(r1 => r1["Test_Item_Code"] == "V0002").First()["Test_Data"]